# Ada: Check if OUT parameters have changed (from NULL) after procedure call

Tags: parameters, null, ada, out

Given a procedure with several OUT parameters, of different types, all initialised as `null`, how can I check if their **value changes** after the procedure call? i.e. If they are no longer `null`.

---

I thought there might be a better way than stringing  `if (OUTP_1 /= null) and (OUTP_2 /= null) ... then ALL_FINE := TRUE;`.

Having an easy to apply solution would be great, since I have actually *many* procedures for which to check this. Not looking for elegance, but rather ease of implementation.

Answer (score 6):

Ada treats OUT parameters as uninitialized. If they are not assigned a value within the procedure their values are not to be trusted.

You can run SPARK analysis on the procedures. The SPARK analyzers will identify un-set OUT parameters as uninitialized variables.

Alternatively, if you are using Ada 2012 you can define post-conditions for each procedure. If using an earlier version of Ada you can use PRAGMA ASSERT to create similar post-conditions.

Setting the parameters as NULL before calling the procedure has no effect upon OUT parameters. You seem to be confusing OUT parameters with IN OUT parameters.

Comment: Any pointers or tutorials on SPARK analytics? I'm using Ada 95, so could you expand on the creation of post-conditions through PRAGMA ASSERT? If assigning a value to an OUT parameter has no effect on it, would it raise a compiler error or keep quiet about it?

Comment: Assigning a value to an OUT parameter does have an effect on the parameter. The OUT parameter value is treated as uninitialized until you assign a value to the parameter. 

Pragma Assert was added for Ada 2005. Is there any way you could use a more modern version of the language? SPARK is also very difficult with Ada 95.

Comment: Not really. I am stuck with Ada 95.

Comment: Have you experimented with your compiler in this area? A little test I ran shows that the value of an OUT parameter may change from an initialized value even if no value is assigned in the execution of the procedure. This is not entirely surprising since the OUT parameter is treated as un-initialized by the procedure. Simply checking for NOT NULL is insufficient to determine if the value has been assigned within the procedure.

Comment: If you want to be able to ensure that the NULL value is retained as an initial value you need to change the parameter calling mode to IN OUT, which may also be a problem if you are dealing with legacy code.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a difficult issue. Would changing the parameter from OUT to IN OUT just for testing imply potentially hazardous changes?

Comment: You must do a hazard analysis to determine what the hazards might be. What could go wrong, what are the effects of improper behavior? Both OUT and IN OUT parameters produce side effects. Only IN OUT parameters carry side effects into the procedure you are testing, and those side effects are only important if the procedure reads the IN OUT value before changing it.